# How can I get a HorizontalScrollView to scroll to the correct position after adding padding to its child?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a LinearLayout (with horizontal orientation) inside a HorizontalScrollView. When the user clicks on an element of the LinearLayout, I want it to always scroll so that the selected element is flush with the left side of the ScrollView.

Right now, the following code in my OnClickListener usually accomplishes what I want:

```
ReadView readView = (ReadView) view;
horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(readView.getLeft(), 0);
```

Except in cases where the element is near the end of the `LinearLayout`, which makes sense. In an attempt to solve this, I add padding to the right side of the LinearLayout:

```
ReadView readView = (ReadView) view;
horizontalLayout.setPadding(0,0, 1000, 0);
horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(readView.getLeft(), 0);
```

Except...that doesn't work. I've verified that the padding is being added correctly, but the ScrollView isn't scrolling based on the padding.

I want to be able to remove the padding afterward, so that when the user scrolls without clicking, they won't see the extra padding, so I'd prefer to be able to do this in the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: use a `ViewTreeObserver`.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = horizontalLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDraw() {
                    vto.removeOnDrawListener(this);
                    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(readView.getLeft(), 0);
                    /* ... */
                }
            });
            horizontalLayout.setPadding(0,0, 1000, 0);
```